# Palm Pre Emulator Internet connection problem

Tags: palm-pre

I am running the Google Map application which is part of Palm Emulator. On launching the application , it displays "Google Maps requires internet connection". When i run emulator, do I  need to configure the network settings .

Similar thing happens when i enter some url in the browser its says " Error Loading Page 2028".

I assumed that emulator will the take the pc Lan setting on which the emulator is running to access to internet.

Can someone help and highlight some info on the same ??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem and solved it by rooting into the emulator via novacom, and updating /etc/resolv.conf to a proper nameserver.  For some reason it hadn't set that correctly.

To check if this is your problem, try (from your rooted emulator) pinging "google.com", and then try pinging just its IP.  If the latter works but not the former, this is your issue.

You can check the output of "ip route show" and use the default gateway shown as the nameserver to set it to.

Also, the emulator setup should default to NAT, so no, extra configuration should not be required as indicated by other poster.

Answer (score 1):

The Palm Pre Emulator works atop Sun's [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). If the emulator is not able to connect to the Internet or any existing network from the get-go, you should skim through the [documentation](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/3.0.6/UserManual.pdf) provided on the VirtualBox site as well as the helpful [HOWTOs and tutorials](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/User_HOWTOS) that explain how to set up different kinds of networking on VirtualBox.